# UIScrollView with UICollectionView Child

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, scroll

I have a `scrollView`, and inside the `scrollview` contains a `collectionView`.

With one single swipe, I would like to scroll the outer `scrollView` until the inner `scrollView` comes in frame and then stop the outer scroll and scroll the inner (all this in one swipe).
So basically I want to pass the scrolling from outer to inner on-the-fly.

I am able to achieve this effect however I must remove my finger, and then press my finger down again and scroll the other view:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
//general scroll info
CGFloat scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

//if the scrollview reaches the top then pass the touch to my collection view
//however i must remove my finger and press again in order to scroll the collectionview
if (scrollView == _scrollView && scrollOffset >= 120){
    [_scrollView setScrollEnabled:NO];
    [_scrollView setBounces:NO];

    [_collectionView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [_collectionView setBounces:YES];

    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 120) animated:YES];
}else if (scrollView != _scrollView && scrollOffset < 0){
    [_scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [_scrollView setBounces:YES];

    [_collectionView setScrollEnabled:NO];
    [_collectionView setBounces:NO];
    [self.collectionView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];
}

}
```

I would like to be able to do this without having to remove my finger.

Any thoughts?

Comment: UICollectionView is a scroll view itself, why do you need all this trouble with outer scroll view?

Comment: it is necessary for the effect I am trying to achieve.
I want to place an image above the collectionView, then I scroll the scrollView above the imageview and once it the imageView is fully covered, the collectionView should begin to scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by creating a large parent UIScrollView the size of the screen.
Inside that scrollview I had my UICollectionView and my image inside a another UIScrollView (for a parallax effect).

So it looks like this:

- ScrollView (size of screen)

  - ScrollView

    - ImageView
  - CollectionView

Once I reached the top of the screen with my collectionView I changed the content offset on the collectionview based on the scroll of the parent scrollview.